# Using state in child component received from parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props

When I click on the menu in GeneralNav I successfully switch between true or false.

This menuState once again is passed successfully to Overlay via HomePage.

Though I'm not able to toggle the right classes in Overlay to hide or show the menu. Can someone explain me a correct workflow to add the classes on my EasyFlexCol component to show or hide it? Been stuck for a while now.

Thanks!

```
class GeneralNav extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <div
          className="nav-burger-box menu-action"
          onClick={this.props.toggleMenu}
        >
          <div className="nav-burger-top" />
          <div className="nav-burger-bottom" />
        </div>
    );
  }
}



class HomePage extends Component {
  state = {
    showMenu: false
  };

  toggleMenu = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState(state => ({ showMenu: !state.showMenu }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
          <OverlayMenu menuState={this.state.showMenu}/>
          <HeaderFullscreen />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}



class OverlayMenu extends Component {

  state = {
    showMenu: "overlay-menu-wrapper bg-color-dark overlay-menu-wrapper display-block",
    hideMenu: "overlay-menu-wrapper bg-color-dark overlay-menu-wrapper"
  };

  render() {
    let menuState = this.props.menuState
    console.log(menuState)
    return (
      <EasyFlexCol style={"here I want to add the right class to show or hide the overlay menu"}>

      </EasyFlexCol>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do using ternary operation like this :

i.e if menuState is true show showMenu else vice versa

```
            <EasyFlexCol className={menuState ? showHide.showMenu : showHide.hideMenu}>
            </EasyFlexCol>
```

here is working example for your refrence : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wj49ol

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary operator when rendering.

```
class OverlayMenu extends Component {
    render() {
        const showHide= { // Assuming that strings below are valid CSS class names
            showMenu: "overlay-menu-wrapper bg-color-dark overlay-menu-wrapper display-block",
            hideMenu: "overlay-menu-wrapper bg-color-dark overlay-menu-wrapper"
        };

        let menuState = this.props.menuState
        console.log(menuState)
        return (
            <EasyFlexCol className={menuState ? showHide.showMenu : showHide.hideMenu}>
            </EasyFlexCol>
        );
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can compose style of `<EasyFlexCol/>` component dynamically

```
class OverlayMenu extends Component {
    render() {
        style={ display: 'block' }
        let menuState = this.props.menuState
        return (
            <EasyFlexCol className={'some-default-class'} style={menuState ? style : {}}>
            </EasyFlexCol>
        );
    }
}
```

Both example assume that `<EasyFlexCol/>` has either `className` property or `style` property.